# Caches API not working on VPS Debian server

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nginx, caching, vps

I have a Vue app running on a VPS Debian server with nginx.
I use the Cache API for caching data and loading it into the app.
When the app was uploaded on my ftp it worked fine, after I deployed it on the server, however,
I receive an error :

`Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: caches is not defined`

The code that runs the cache api is:

```
const getCachedResource = async (type) => {
    const url = `${DATA_URL}${type}.json`

    const cache = await caches.open(cacheName);
    if (cache) {
        const response = await cache.match(url)
        if (!response) {
            return undefined
        }
        const jsonResponse = await response.json()
        return jsonResponse
    }
}
```

Is there anything I need to enable/fix on the VPS to get it going?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the Caches API requires HTTPS. When I added the certificate the issue was fixed.